# The phrase "be opposed to something" has the same meaning of "oppose something". How can it be possible?

Tags: phrase-meaning, passive-voice

The phrase **oppose something** means "to disagree with something and try to prevent it from happening", which makes me think **X is opposed** means X is what someone disagrees with and tries to prevent from happening. But **be opposed to something** has the same meaning as **oppose something**. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you're puzzled because you've analyzed

> 1a. I am opposed to slavery

as the passive transposition of

> 1b. *I* oppose **slavery**.

But that's wrong.  The passive transposition would take the **direct object** of 1b (*slavery*) and make it the subject and take the subject of 1b (*I*) and make it the **object** of the preposition *by*. (While, of course using the passive form of the verb.)

> 2. *Slavery* is opposed by **me**.

In 1a, the main verb is *am*, a copular verb linking the subject (*I*) with its predicate complement, here a past participle (*opposed*).  That is, the sentence describes the state of the speaker, namely in opposition.  *Opposed* licenses a prepositional phrase (with *to*) as a complement to tell us the target of the opposition.

Comment: My thinking is as follows: the subject in 1a (I) is the patient of the action "oppose" and  the subject  in 1b (I) is the agent of the action "oppose". So, 1a and 1b are incompatible. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: *I* is the subject in 1a  but not the patient of the action *oppose* because there is no action.  The word in 1a is *opposed* and it's a predicate complement, not a main verb.  The syntax of 1a is different from the sentence *1c. In the upcoming election, I **am opposed** by a Christian Democrat*.  In 1c *am opposed* is a passive voice verb.  In 1a *am opposed* is copular verb+predicate complement.

Comment: 2a) Politics doesn't interest me.
2b) I am not interested in politics.

2b has the form of "copular verb+predicate complement".
At the same time, it is possible to consider 2b as a passive voice form of 2a 
and the subject (I) as the patient of the action "interest".
On the other hand, there is at least superficially a conflict of semantic role between the subject of 1a (I) and that of 1b (I). So, I thought there was a reason for that. For example, the reason might be that a misuse of the verb "oppose" had been gradually accepted as a legitimate use.

Comment: @Aki 2a/b forms a nice example, but I think that if you want 2b to be a passive construction you have to supply an agent: *I am not interested **by** politics*, which I think is precluded by the prepositional phrase with *in*.  Perhaps you can think of a counterexample.  It seems to me that the confusion in 1a/b is one of lexical order.  I don't understand what you mean by the "misuse of the verb".

Comment: Even if 2b is not a passive construction as you pointed out, 
I can still convince myself of the meaning of  the adjective "interested" 
as the natural extension of the meaning of the past participle "interested". But, I can't do so for "opposed".
I suppose the past participle "interested" had become recognized as an adjective over time. 
What I mean by "misuse" is such a situation 
where the past participle "opposed" was confused with the present participle "opposing".

Comment: @Aki The test is whether the participle can be used attributively (*the opposed party*) as well as predicatively (*he is opposed*).  The former is far less used than the latter, but here's an example from a book on Canada: "When, however, group members do favour the **opposed** party, their opinions are likely to be strongly in keeping with the party position."  Past participles carry the aspect of past duration; present participles, the aspect of continuation.  I don't see how these get confused.

Comment: Do you mean the participle "opposed" failed the test? 
I know my example of "misuse" is unlikely one. 
But, it could explain the contrast between the meaning of the participle and that of the predicative adjective. 
All adjectives derived from past participles that I can think of have the predictable meanings from their origins.
On the other hand the meaning of the predicative adjective "opposed" 
is in a sense opposite to that of the past participle "opposed".

Comment: @Aki No, I mean *opposed* passed the test: the *opposed* party [attributive] is the party that is *opposed* [predicative].  Do you think it means something else?  What am I missing?

Comment: I thought it was a test to prove how much the adjective retains the meaning of the past participle from which it comes from, 
and the rarerity of its occurence as attributive adjective implied "almost zero". 
Then, could you explain what the test result shows us?

Comment: You seem to think that the attributive use of *opposed* means the opposite of the predicative use.  They mean the same things, as my example shows.  Or at least I think it does.  I think *group members who favour the opposed party* means group members who favor the other group, the one to which they don't belong, i.e., the group they usually oppose.  No?

Comment: Suppose that they are Democrats. So the opposed party is the Republican Party.
Group members favour the opposed Party.
3a)The **opposed** party is the Republican Party.
3b)The Republican party is usually **opposed** by them.
3c)They are **opposed** to the Republican Party.
I feel that the use of **opposed** in 3c) is opposite to that of 3a) and 3b).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38167/discussion-between-deadrat-and-aki).

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways of saying the same thing. For example: He agrees to meet on Friday. He's agreeable to meeting on Friday. It'll take time to accustom myself to the changes. It'll take time to get accustomed to the changes. There are many such examples. The same holds true for vocabulary. For example yesterday evening and last night.

Comment: This isn't a bad answer, but I feel I should point out that the explanation of your example is slightly off, as it is not different ways of saying the same thing: "He agrees to meet on Friday." means that he has made a decision. A meeting on Friday is fine and will go ahead. "He's agreeable to meeting on Friday" simply means that the possibility of a meeting on Friday exists and he's leaning towards it, but he hasn't necessarily made a decision yet one way or the other.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agreeable          "Ready to consent or submit: I am agreeable to your plan." (not much difference from I agree to your plan. Sometimes business English uses more words in an attempt to sound formal)

Comment: Do you really think that I asked this question because I don't think there are different ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: My apologies. I don't know what you're asking, then. I hope someone does, my friend.

Comment: You don't have to apologize. I was not offended. I was just surprised. Maybe, my question is too ambiguous. P.S. use "@username" to notify the person to whom you wrote unless the person is the post author.